# Chrome extension Native messaging

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, chromium, chrome-native-messaging

Google is phasing out the use of Npapi plugins.  The preferred alternative would be Native messaging.  see: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging-host
In the example a windows executable is defined in the manifest file.  It also states that the registry needs to be updated to reflect the name defined in the manifest.  My question is, how is this all to be done from a crx file as they cannot modify the registry? Also does Google permit .exe files to be added to the crx?

Answer (score 3):

A native messaging extension requires two installations. One the Crx file(extension) and second the installer which modifies the registry and installs the executable to be called by the extension. The extensions will be rendered useless unless you can bundle the two in one installation package which can be done.

Comment: The next logical step for me is here (how to install extension programatically): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211772/how-to-install-a-chrome-extension-programmatically

Comment: Just as you say, two installs are needed. In theory, if your user runs an .exe file, that can be used to install the extension via the registry. This does have a few limitations: the .crx must be published on the CWS and AFAIK chrome must be restarted afterwards.