# Programmatically installing a chrome extension to the default profile

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to install an extension to the default profile from the command line or programmatically? Preferably the extension should be fetched at runtime from chrome-store shipping it packaged with the installer is fine too.

Comment: Check out this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211772/how-to-install-a-chrome-extension-programmatically). It seems to ask a similar question..

Comment: I'm going to close it as duplicate, since the accepted answer there contains what's needed.